# Concurrency control mechanisms to be used in GridDB to prevent data conflicts and ensure data integrity during concurrent read and write operations

Tags: griddb

I'm developing a multi-threaded web application that allows users to simultaneously read and update shared data stored in GridDB. The application experiences heavy concurrency, and I want to ensure that data conflicts are handled correctly to maintain data integrity.

I would like to understand the recommended concurrency control mechanisms in GridDB to prevent race conditions, deadlocks, and inconsistent data states. Also, I'm interested in learning how to implement row-level locking, optimistic concurrency control, or any other suitable techniques in GridDB to handle concurrent read and write operations effectively.